# Hide/Unhide picklist using jquery on VFP

Tags: javascript, visualforce

For some reason, the init in the javascript hides everything BUT the joint billing partner code 
[image: picture of after init]

VFP:

```
       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="PPJPN">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Joint Billing Partner Name" id="Property__Joint___Name_lbl" for="Property__Joint___Name"><font size="3px" color="red">*</font></apex:outputLabel>
               <apex:inputField value="{!DealerProperty__c.jointBillingPartnerName__c}"    id="Property__Joint___Name"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="PPJPC">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Joint Billing Partner Code" id="Property__Joint___Code_lbl" for="Property__Joint___Code"><font size="3px" color="red">*</font></apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!DealerProperty__c.jointBillingPartnerCode__c}" id="Property__Joint___Code"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Javascript:

```
     if(propModelVal.includes("JOINT")){
        $("[id$=Property__Joint___Name]").show();
        $("[id$=Property__Joint___Code]").show();
        $("[id$=Property__Joint___Name_lbl]").show();
        $("[id$=Property__Joint___Code_lbl]").show();
    }else{
        $("[id$=Property__Joint___Name]").hide();
        $("[id$=Property__Joint___Code]").hide();
        $("[id$=Property__Joint___Name_lbl]").hide();
        $("[id$=Property__Joint___Code_lbl]").hide();
    }
```

edit: it is a dependant picklist if that makes any difference

edit2: I looked at the source code and the id on the page is PP:PF:PM:PI:PPJPC:Property__Joint___Code which means the jquery selector should work.

there are actually 2 ids, one for the input and one for the selector, would that make a difference?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[id$=Property__Joint___Code]")
```

this is an "ends with" selector being used on the `id` attribute of the rendered HTML element

```
<apex:inputField value="{!DealerProperty__c.jointBillingPartnerCode__c}" 
    id="Property__Joint___Code"/>
```

This VF tag bound to the custom field on your object is likely producing an `id` on the HTML element which does not end with `Property__Joint___Code` and so because no elements were found matching that selector, nothing was hidden.

If you inspect the source of that page you can see what the id value is and adjust your jQuery selector appropriately or you can use the utility provided by Salesforce for this, which is the [global $Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm) reference.

Your jQuery syntax for the selector might look like this instead in your source code:

```
$('[id="{!$Component.Property__Joint___Code}"]');
```

which would then be rendered into the page as something like this with the dynamically generated `id`:

```
$('[id="yourPageId:yourPageBlockId:yourPageBlockSectionId:PPJPC:Property__Joint___Code"]')
```

Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/126076/660

Comment: Okay, I will test this out but I have 1 further question about it. I have this being hidden on page load and then the possibility to be shown and hidden again by propmodelval being changed. If i change propmodelval to contain "JOINT' it will show all 4 fields, if I change it away again, it will hide all 4 using these same lines. Just wrapped within an onchange for that propmodelval picklist. It hides all 4 though and doesn't leave 1 out.